# Restricted access to remote ports

Tags: amazon-ec2, tcp, port

Kind of a weird scenario:

I have an instance running using EC2 on AWS. I can ping different ports (opened or closed) when I am on certain internet connections (ie. work wifi, phone 3G, home wifi) -- they immediately return expected results or refused connections, depending on what ports I am using.

On different internet connections (ie. public wifi, mobile wifi, even via ethernet at work) the request hangs. It doesn't refuse connection, but just hangs until operation timeout.

On Chrome, in `chrome://net-internals/#events`, it always hangs at the Socket 'TCP_CONNECT_ATTEMPT' step:

```
890298: SOCKET
my-domain.com:81
Start Time: 2018-05-31 12:11:21.142

t=6421 [st=0] +SOCKET_ALIVE  [dt=?]
               --> source_dependency = 890297 (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_JOB)
t=6421 [st=0]   +TCP_CONNECT  [dt=?]
                 --> address_list = ["22.333.22.22:81"]
t=6421 [st=0]     +TCP_CONNECT_ATTEMPT  [dt=?]
                   --> address = "22.333.22.22:81"
```

Then it times out, updating like so:

```
890298: SOCKET
my-domain.com:81
Start Time: 2018-05-31 12:11:21.142

t= 6421 [st=    0] +SOCKET_ALIVE  [dt=75230]
                    --> source_dependency = 890297 (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_JOB)
t= 6421 [st=    0]   +TCP_CONNECT  [dt=75230]
                      --> address_list = ["22.333.22.22:81"]
t= 6421 [st=    0]     +TCP_CONNECT_ATTEMPT  [dt=75230]
                        --> address = "22.333.22.22:81"
t=81651 [st=75230]     -TCP_CONNECT_ATTEMPT
                        --> os_error = 60
t=81651 [st=75230]   -TCP_CONNECT
                      --> net_error = -118 (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)
t=81651 [st=75230] -SOCKET_ALIVE
```

Why would it work on some internet connections, and then block others?

Comment: Not all networks allow communication over all ports. It probably hangs because it is still trying but hasn't timed out yet. You might try using the nmap utility to see which ports you can access depending on what network you are on. You could also use SSH tunneling to get around blocked ports.

Comment: @dmohr thanks for  the suggestion of nmap, it helped me! On one network it shows the suspect port as 'open' while on the other one it shows it as 'filtered'. This definitely points me in a better direction